# CFAttributedString replace occurrences of string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, string, ios5

I know that in a CFAttributedString does not respond to any method like the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method of NSString, and I cannot find a method that can do that using a CF(Mutable)AttributedString.

I want to replace some text in the string with the same text but another color, e. g., I have the string `@"This is a text"` and I want to change the color of the word "text".

I hope the question is clear enough, if it isn't, ask me.

Thanks.

Comment: So... you do not want to change the text, just the attribute (font color for example) of a sub-range, correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think to change the text is the easiest way, but I don't know, so if you have another solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a category on `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (MySearchAndReplaceCategory)

- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes forOccurencesOfString:(NSString *)target
{
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, self.length);

    while ( searchRange.length )
    {
        NSRange range = [self.string rangeOfString:target options:0 range:searchRange];
        if ( ! range.length )
            break;

        [self setAttributes:attributes range:range];
        searchRange.length = NSMaxRange(searchRange) - NSMaxRange(range);
        searchRange.location = NSMaxRange(range);
    }
}

@end
```

Then use something like that:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(__bridge id) color.CGColor
                                                       forKey:(__bridge id) kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is a text"];
[text setAttributes:attributes forOccurencesOfString:@"text"];
```

Comment: I'll try it and if it works, I'll accept your answer. But I want a CFAttributedString, that is similar but not equal, so I will try to change it a bit

Comment: `CFMutableAttributedStringRef` and `NSMutableAttributedString` are totally interchangeable as documented in the [Toll-Free Bridging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) documentation.

Comment: Ok sorry I throught that they aren't exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

re:  Toll-Free Bridging

CFAtttributeString and NSAttributeString have different attributes keys.

Ex. Color Mac OS X:

NSForegroundColorAttributeName - NSColor - Default blackColor 
kCTForegroundColorAttributeName - The value associated with this attribute must be a CGColor object. Default value is black.